# Is it safe to call the Sidekiq API from inside perform?

Tags: ruby, sidekiq, job-scheduling

Nothing seems to prevent a `perform` method to use the Sidekiq API. It should be safe in read-only mode.

What if it calls a "write" methods ? Especially when this method acts on the current job itself.

We would like to reschedule a job without creating a new job because we need to track the job completion with the `sidekiq-status` gem from another worker.

Using `MyWorker.perform_in` or `MyWorker.perform_at` to reschedule the job from inside the worker creates a new job, making it difficult to track the total completion. We're thinking of using `Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.find` and the `reschedule` method but it seems awkward and potentially dangerous to reschedule a job that is about to complete.

Does Sidekiq and its API support this use case ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to hack something together but it'll be really slow if you try to modify the Sets and Lists in Redis directly.  They aren't designed to be used that way.

The official Sidekiq solution to this problem is a Batch.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Batches#status

You create a one-job batch.  If the job needs to be rescheduled, it adds a new job to the Batch to be executed later.  Your other worker just checks the status of the overall Batch and if it is 100% complete.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We will have a look at the Batch feature to solve this issue.